# Retry does not work with Datacard

Tags: asterisk, phone-call

The essence of the problem. Retry does not work with Datacard when the device is busy.For example, if 2 call files started immediately only one will work, the second falls with error and no longer tries to dial:

```
[Nov 25 12:47:35] NOTICE[5801] pbx_spool.c: Call failed to go through, reason (0) Call Failure (not BUSY, and not NO_ANSWER, maybe
 Circuit busy or down?)
```

Here how it looks in call log:

```
12:47:27 [74c414f9-b5b9-4c83-9ebd-79c7e417ca79]:{Type:1,Number:0038050xxxxxxx,Secret:xxx,Service:1}
12:47:35 [27a262f5-70dc-42bf-b023-0878712ac6cb]:{Type:1,Number:0038050yyyyyyy,Secret:xxx,Service:1}
12:47:49 [74c414f9-b5b9-4c83-9ebd-79c7e417ca79]: Call to +38050xxxxxxx ended with status OK.
```

Here is my call file:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
CALL_SPOOL_DIR="/var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/"
CALL="/var/spool/asterisk/tmp/alarm-iax.call"


echo "Channel: Datacard/datacard0/$1">$CALL
echo "CallerId: 666">>$CALL
echo "MaxRetries: 10" >>$CALL
echo "RetryTime: 45">>$CALL
echo "WaitTime: 30">>$CALL
echo "Context: monitoring-alarm">>$CALL
echo "Extension: s">>$CALL
echo "Priority: 1">>$CALL
echo "Setvar: STATUS=$2">>$CALL
echo "Setvar: SERVICE=$3">>$CALL
echo "Setvar: NUM=$1">>$CALL
echo "Setvar: UID=$4">>$CALL
mv $CALL $CALL_SPOOL_DIR
```

extension

```
[monitoring-alarm]
exten = s,1,Wait(0.5)
exten = s,2,Set(VOLUME(TX)=-5)
exten = s,3,Playback(${STATUS})
exten = s,4,Playback(ru_service)
exten = s,5,Playback(${SERVICE})
exten = s,6,Hangup
exten = h,1,System(echo ${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},"GMT-2","%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")}[${UID}]: Call to ${NUM} ended with status OK. >>
/var/log/informer.log)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via Local channel:

Change call file to

```
 Channel: Local/$1@datacard/n
 Set: datacardchan=datacard0
```

Add to extensions.conf

```
 [datacard]
 exten => _X.,1,Dial(Datacard/${datacardchan}/${EXTEN},,); dial 
 exten => _X.,n,Dumpchan; to see variables. remove in production
 exten => _X.,n,Congestion; send congestion to pbx_spool
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'm not sure, that i understood the syntax right, but i did everything just like in your answer and got:
NOTICE[12958] chan_local.c: No such extension/context +38050xxx@datacard while calling Local channel
NOTICE[12958] channel.c: Unable to call channel Local/+38050xxx@datacard/n
NOTICE[12958] pbx_spool.c: Call failed to go through, reason (0) Call Failure (not BUSY, and not NO_ANSWER, maybe Circui
t busy or down?)
NOTICE[12958] pbx_spool.c: Queued call to Local/+38050xxx@datacard/n expired without completion after 0 attempts

Comment: replace _X. with _+X. in context.

Comment: now it actually makes call but the situation still same - only one call (the first one).
WARNING[6629] channel.c: [datacard0] Request to call on device which can not make call at this moment
WARNING[6629] app_dial.c: Unable to create channel of type 'Datacard' (cause 44 - Requested channel not availabl
e)
NOTICE[6628] pbx_spool.c: Call failed to go through, reason (8) Congestion (circuits busy)
NOTICE[6628] pbx_spool.c: Queued call to Local/+38050xxx@datacard/n expired without completion after 0 attem
pts
NOTICE[6622] pbx_spool.c: Call completed to Local/+38050yyy@datacard/n

Comment: but now you see what is dooing. so you can help it work ok,for example create loop.

Comment: ps. wait time have be less then retry time.

Comment: I think wait time should not be mandatory less then retry time. Retry time starts, when call handling ends with some hangup code other than normal circuit congestion.

Answer (score 0):

Arheops forced me to make some research. This end up with the next:

To handle retry with Datacard you should set WaitTime value in call file based to formula **max quantity of an instantaneous calls** * 2 * (**playback duration** + **delay between retries**). In my case its 4-5 calls about 10 secs per each + 20 sec = 2*150  200-300 sec would be enough. If you miss that you will get DIALSTATUS == CANCEL or DIALSTATUS == CHANUNAVAIL when WaitTime goes out.

```
[datacard]
exten=_+X.,1,Set(ERROR_LOOP=0)
exten=_+X.,n(call),Dial(Datacard/${datacardchan}/${EXTEN},,M(alert^${STATUS}^${SERVICE}))
exten=_+X.,n(case1),GotoIf($[${HANGUPCAUSE} = 44]?error:case2)
exten=_+X.,n(case2),GotoIf($[${HANGUPCAUSE} = 17]?error:end)
exten=_+X.,n(error),System(echo ${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},"GMT-2","%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")}[${UID}]: Datacard is unavailable now. HANGUPCAUSE =  ${HANGUPCAUSE}. ERROR_LOOP stage = ${ERROR_LOOP}. >> /var/log/informer-test.log)
exten=_+X.,n,Set(ERROR_LOOP=$[${ERROR_LOOP} + 1])
exten=_+X.,n,Wait(20)
exten=_+X.,n,GotoIf($[${ERROR_LOOP} <= 5]?call)
exten=_+X.,n,GotoIf($[${DIALSTATUS} = CANCEL]?retry)
exten=_+X.,n(end),Hangup
exten=_+X.,n(retry),Hangup(21)
exten=h,1,System(echo ${STRFTIME(${EPOCH},"GMT-2","%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")}[${UID}]: Calling process to ${NUM} ended with DIALSTATUS = ${DIALSTATUS}. >> /var/log/informer-test.log)

[macro-alert]
exten=s,1,Set(VOLUME(TX)=-5)
exten=s,n,Wait(0.5)
exten=s,n,Playback(${ARG1})
exten=s,n,Playback(ru_service)
exten=s,n,Playback(${ARG2})
```

call-file

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
CALL_SPOOL_DIR="/var/spool/asterisk/outgoing/"
CALL="/var/spool/asterisk/tmp/alarm-iax.call"

echo "Channel: Local/$1@datacard/n">$CALL
echo "Set: datacardchan=datacard0">>$CALL
echo "WaitTime: 300">>$CALL
echo "Context: datacard">>$CALL

mv $CALL $CALL_SPOOL_DIR
```